# how to customise cin to read our own formats

Tags: c++

Consider an example where you have friends A B and C and they go for a trip and each spend their amount and finally you need to split the amount equally among them
INPUT FORMAT:
A, B, C
A 100 DRINKS
B 200 SNACKS
A 300 TICKETS

Problem is how could I read the first line A, B, C and then the rest of the lines

Comment: Your file is separated by lines? So first line is "A, B, C" then the second line is "A 100 DRINKS" the third line "B 200 SNACKS" and the fourth line "A 300 TICKETS"?

Answer (score 2):

You create a class to hold the information:

```
struct MyClass
{
   enum friend_t {
     A, B, C
   } friend;

   std::map<friend_t, unsigned int> drink_count;
   std::map<friend_t, unsigned int> snack_count;
   std::map<friend_t, unsigned int> ticket_count;
};
```

Then you define an operator that can be used in isolation to extract this information:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyClass& obj)
{
    // Here put a collection of `is >> ...` operations to do what you need
}
```

Now, from the calling scope, the operation is encapsulated, e.g.:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    while (std::cin >> obj) {}
}
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out the actual contents of the `operator>>` function. This counts as input parsing to a degree, but your input data looks simple enough to do with a simple loop and a bunch of `>>` calls on `is`.

Comment: What if you don't know how many friends are there. That is it can be A, B, C, D or it can be A, C, Z, G, H, K, DS, GB

Comment: @Vino: Then adjust accordingly. But the question doesn't say that.